# Is it safe to enable ”Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *“ (wildcard) for a public and readonly webservice?

Tags: security, cors

Enabling CORS has several [security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713644/when-is-it-safe-to-enable-cors):

- CSRF
- exposure of protected data

But are there any issues for a public and readonly webservice to enable global CORS?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

My assumptions:

- CSRF is not relevant, because webservice is readonly.
- stealing of protected data is not relevant, because webservice is public.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here’s [something relevant from the Fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#basic-safe-cors-protocol-setup) (which defines CORS):

> #### Basic safe CORS protocol setup
>
> For resources where data is protected through IP authentication or a firewall (unfortunately relatively common still), using the CORS protocol is unsafe. (This is the reason why the CORS protocol had to be invented.)
>
> However, otherwise using the following header is safe:
>
> ```
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> ```
>
> Even if a resource exposes additional information based on cookie or HTTP authentication, using the above header will not reveal it. It will share the resource with APIs such as `XMLHttpRequest`, much like it is already shared with `curl` and `wget`.
>
> Thus in other words, if a resource cannot be accessed from a random device connected to the web using `curl` and `wget` the aforementioned header is not to be included. If it can be accessed however, it is perfectly fine to do so.

And the author of the Fetch/CORS spec goes into a bit more detail [in a related blog posting](https://annevankesteren.nl/2012/12/cors-101):

> It is completely safe to augment any resource with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` as long as the resource is not part of an intranet (behind a firewall). In other words, a URL you can fetch from a server on the internet using `wget` or `curl`. For your basic web site this encompasses all resources on the site. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (part of CORS) tells the browser the resource can be shared.
>
> Even if the resource includes confidential information based on cookies or HTTP authentication data in the request, including the header and sharing the resource is still safe, since the browser will make the request without any cookies or HTTP authentication data. And if the browser did make the request with cookies or HTTP authentication data, it would never share the resource because that would require an additional header, `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, and a different value for the aforementioned header.
>
> So go ahead and safely share your public data with other applications!

Answer (score 1):

If it is a public API then CORS should be enabled for all requests.
One of the best security approach for public APIs is using app keys in request headers.

Comment: What does 'using app keys' mean?

Comment: When making HTTP requests,include a header in your request that can be authenticated by the server.Your server will therefore only process requests with authenticated headers.This header is the app key.

Comment: Are app keys an alternative to cookies, or in addition to cookies?