# Samsung internet CORS only sends OPTIONS request

Tags: javascript, cors, samsung-mobile

When using the "Samsung internet" browser on an Android device, it fails to do Ajax (some work) requests. After some debugging I saw that the browser only sends the options request (which succeeds) but does not send the corresponding post request afterwards.

You can try yourself by visiting my Dev site, select ok on the confirm prompt, click on login and try to login with random data

https://dev.gameplaylan.de

Comment: Hi there, my bet is you forgot to paste your link ;)

Comment: Actually it's been there, but the https was all capital and so seems to have some kinda replacement logic which looks after that ‍♂️ well, now it's there

Comment: Just on a side note: Don't ever use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in any production code. It's an awful security hole. And if you are using cookies, it won't work with CORS, you would then need a reverse proxy.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 you don't have a choice on webview though

Comment: Thanks for the side node will change it soon ^^

Comment: The cookie problem is not a problem for me, the application does not need any.

Comment: But this still does not explain the weird behaviour of the Samsung browser... All other browsers work fine...

Comment: Side note on that side note — see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154170/is-it-safe-to-enable-cors-to-for-a-public-and-readonly-webservice/43154277#43154277

Comment: Instead of using the `*` wildcard for the Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Methods response headers, try having the server instead send a list of the explicit method names and header names your frontend sends/needs. Because my guess is that the Samsung browser probably doesn’t recognize the `*` wildcard for the Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Methods response headers. So the preflight isn’t actually succeeding in the Samsung browser — it’s instead failing because the browser isn’t seeing the explicit header names and method names it expects.

Comment: Try opening http://web-platform-tests.live/fetch/api/cors/cors-preflight-star.any.html in the Samsung browser. If you don’t see *10 pass* and instead see any failures, then that’s an indication it’s not handling the `*` wildcard for Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Methods as expected in at least some cases.

Comment: That's been it! 2 of 10 tests fail (the wildcard tests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems like the Samsung internet browser doesn't handle wildcard access-control headers.

So I need to switch to an explicit list...