# Asp.Net WebApi works with GET but not POST

Tags: jquery, asp.net, http-post, asp.net-web-api2, http-get

I am using Asp.Net web forms with WebAPI 2. I have a method which works with GET but when I use POST then it doesn't work. If you see below there is a break point inside that method and it doesn't even reach there when calling POST. Strangely when I use Postman to test the method then it works with POST. What am I doing wrong?

My jquery code

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'MyController/GetUserDetail',
   type: 'POST',
   async: true,
   dataType: 'json',
   data:
   {
      "search": myvariable
   },
    success: function (response) {
   }
});
```

My Web API method. When using [HttpGet] and also changing jquery from POST to GET, then it works. But for POST this method is never called as breakpoint never hits and I don't receive any error either.

```
[HttpPost]
public User GetUserDetail(string search)
{      //breakpoint here
}
```

My route config

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
}
```

Comment: `I don't receive any error either` there will be an error in the response. You can use the network tab of the console to find it, after making the request in your JS code.

Comment: what does the GET action look like? is it possible it's "swallowing" your request (maybe it does not have a [HttpGet] attribute)?

Comment: 1) check the url is correct (browser network tab) - if you have deployed it might need to be `MyApp/MyController/MyAction` use `@Url.Action("GetUserDetail", "MyController")` to be sure (but not if it's in a .js file).  2) Remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute (for now at least, to rule it out) unless you have other overloads - it shouldn't be a POST anyway as it's clearly a GET "GetUserDetail".

Comment: @LongChalk adding `[HttpGet]` would *limit* to GET, not indicate that's it's a get method.  If there's only one method (as implied, but not specified in OP) then it doesn't need `[HttpGet]`

Comment: @freedomn-m, perhaps it's not a GET/POST issue at all? perhaps you are calling it from a different area/controller in the postman and on the client side? have you considered debugging it by looking at the F12/Network? or requesting a 'MyController/GetUserDetail/' ?

Comment: Yeah I will check via F12/Network tomorrow when I go to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CORS issue. To handle CORS for Web API,  add below settings in web.config file of Web API inside <system.webServer>   section:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

But there is a security risk involved in enabling CORS. A good explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154170/is-it-safe-to-enable-cors-to-for-a-public-and-readonly-webservice).

One more change is necessary in your JavaScript. There is a strange problem with '**data**' setting of $.ajax(),
so you need to embed parameter value within '**url**' as query string:

```
url: 'MyController/GetUserDetail?search=' + myvariable,
```

Comment: I am using .Net 4.6.2 and seems like this is a known problem (as I saw a few posts about it with no solution) with it or it is related to some setting like you posted above about CORS. I am using Windows authentication. The same code works fine in earlier .Net versions. Will check this CORS setting tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

with string search parameter you have not specified [FromBody] or [FromUri] so its bydefault take as fromUri for string type parameters. and you are passing parameter in the body. 
so, try to send parameter as query string...