# WebApi authentication failed on server with Angular

Tags: c#, angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Asp.Net web API 2.0 with Angular 6 for UI. The solution contains the projects for angular and web API.
My solution works fine (I am able to access pages and login) when I am running it on Visual Studio on localhost. However when I deploy the build on server I am unable to login and getting the below error:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx/authenticate' from origin 'http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Answer (score 0):

To quickly handle CORS for Web API,  add below settings in web.config file of Web API inside `<system.webServer>`   section:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

But there is a security risk involved in enabling CORS. A good explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154170/is-it-safe-to-enable-cors-to-for-a-public-and-readonly-webservice).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please let me verify if it works.

Comment: I think the risk enabling CORS in the way you have demonstrate is that requests will be accepted regardless of where the page is hosted. If you properly configure CORS to only accept requests from known pages, then there isn't a security risk.

Comment: @John Risk is not much with common internet based web applications. But if your application has some confidential resources then, as you said, we should allow limited origins.

Comment: @as.if.i.code Well it didn't work. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @SushantRawat Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: @as.if.i.code:The error has changed, now I am getting 401 (Unauthorized) error.

Comment: @SushantRawat Ohh, its good that CORS issue is resolved. For 401 you might need to recheck/reconfigure your request.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add this following code to startup.cs -> configure()

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
```

Comment: I have already used this in my web API code. Can you please suggest something else?

Answer (score 0):

Browser security prevents a web page from making AJAX requests to another domain. This restriction is called the same-origin policy and prevents a malicious site from reading sensitive data from another site. However, sometimes you might want to let other sites call your web API.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Open the file **App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs**. Add the following code to the WebApiConfig.Register method: `config.EnableCors();`

Next, add the **[EnableCors] attribute** to the Controller class

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods not shown...
    }
```

Now you can access the API's