# How do I do cross-origin requests from a WebView rendering local HTML?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webview, cors

I'm rendering a local static HTML file in a WebView that needs to do cross-origin requests to a server I control. Currently those requests are failing because the "Origin" header is being set as `null` by the WebView (probably because it's a local file). I've considered running a local HTTP server in the app and pointing the WebView to that, but then the "Origin" header would be set as `http://localhost`. I'm reluctant to add `localhost` to my CORS whitelist server-side, as I'm not sure what the security implications of that would be.

What would be the best approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have a CORS origin allow list at all, rather than just sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in responses? Are you using an allow list because the requests include credentials?

Comment: Not particularly. I was just under the impression (probably falsely) that I shouldn't use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` if I want to restrict the API calls to domains I control.

Comment: But now that you mention it, it looks like that's only an issue when passing credentials.

Comment: Right — if the requests don’t include credentials, then it’s safe to use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43154277/441757